# How to include "share on social networking sites" link for the video shown in shadowbox.js?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, shadowbox

I have a youtube video to display on my site. I am using shadowbox.js to achieve this.
Now I want to show fshare and tweet links somewhere on the overlay while the user is watching video. How can I do this?